# Does the AWS SDK support indexing and searching for Elasticsearch?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-elasticsearch

In the [AWS Elasticsearch documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-signing-service-requests) they recommend submitting Elasticsearch requests using the AWS SDK. However, I don't find any APIs related to indexing and searching in the SDK. Should indexing and searching instead be done through one of the [Elasticsearch client libraries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK will provide methods to manage the Elasticsearch service (create new domain, list domains, add tags, etc). You will need to interface with Elasticsearch either through a client library or simple HTTPS requests (POST, PUT, GET).